# store a list in request.session in one view and retrieve it in another view django

Tags: django, request, django-sessions

I have a huge list that will be generated dynamically from a csv file in a django view, but i had a requirement to use that list in the next view, so i thought to give a try on `django sessions`

```
def import_products(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.FILES:
           csv_file_data = ...........
           total_records = [row for row in csv_file_data]
           request.session['list_data'] = total_records
           # total_records is `list of lists` of length more than 150
           # do some processing with the list and render the page
    return render_to_response('product/import_products.html') 

def do_something_with_csv_data_from_above_view(request):
    data = request.session['list_data']
    # do some operations with list and render the page
    return render_to_response('website/product/success.html',
```

So as mentioned in the above, i need to use the `total_records` huge list in the `do_something_with_csv_data_from_above_view` view and delete the session by storing it in another variable

So actually how to implement/use exactly the sessions concept(i have read the django docs but could n't able to get the exact concept)

In my case,

1. When a user tries to upload the csv file each time, i am reading the data and storing
   the data as list to session
   ==> Is this the right way to do so ? also i want to store the session variable in
      database concept
2. Because the list was huge, i need to delete it for sure in the next view when i 
   copied it in to another variable

Am i missing anything, can anyone please implement exact code for my above scenario ?

Comment: Why don't you insert the data into database in the first view? You can  receive them from db when you want and use them in the second, third .. etc views?

Comment: Are you current code executed as you wish?

Comment: the functionality was, after uploading the csv, user can select the records(items/products) which he like and can then save it to database (Also before saving i need to do some custom validation :))

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Client side RESTful - This is a RESTful solution but may require a bit more work. You can retrieve the data in the first request to the client and after selecting you can send the selected rows back to the server for processing, CSV etc.
2. Caching: In the first request you can cache your data on the server using a django file system or memcached. In the second request use the cache key (which would be the user session key + some timestamp + whatever else) to fetch the data and store in the db.

If it's a lot of data option 2 may be better.

Comment: but right now, in the first view just storing the list in to a session variable, retrieving the data(list) in the another view, assign it to another variable, delete the actual request.session variable, so it fine in this way ? any problems/side effects will cause by this ?

Comment: It will work but not recommended as against RESTful practices. Also, where is your session data stored? DB or File System? How much data re you storing? If it's an in-memory session then you will suffer side-effects. Make sure it's a database session.

Comment: k thanks, how to make it as a database session, need to make any settings ?

Comment: Django documentation is your friend:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions